# How to check each line of file for UTF-8 and write in another file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I would like to know how I can write to another file on live the lines which are utf-8 encoded. I have a folder containing number of files. I cannot go and check each and every file for UTF-8 character.
I have tried this code:

```
import codecs
try:
    f = codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')
    for line in f:
        pass
    print "Valid utf-8"
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    print "invalid utf-8"
```

This check the whole while is UTF-8 verified or not. But I am trying to check each and every line of the file in a folder and write those lines which are UTF-8 character encoded.
I would like to delete the lines in my file which are not UTF-8 encoded. If while reading line the program get to know that the line is UTF-8 then it should move on to next line, else delete the line which is not UTF-8. I think now it is clear.
I would like to know how I can do it with the help of Python. Kindly let me know.
I am not looking to convert them, but to delete them. Or write to another file the UTF-8 satisfied line from the files.

Comment: *I have seen many characters which are not UTF-8, like that Chinese character or Arabic character.* UTF-8 is not a subset of Unicode symbols. It is a method of encoding Unicode codepoints. Chinese and/or Arabic characters are still valid members of a UTF-8 encoded file.

Comment: *Only the character which are English or normally readable by* ***all*** You'd better clearly define who you mean by *all*. If you include there newborns too, then the set of characters meeting your criteria is empty.

Comment: @Leon Ok then how it is possible that only english characters are left. having other characters must be deleted while inserting in another file.

Comment: If this is Python 3, why are you using `codecs` and using Python 2 syntax ?

Comment: It's very unusual for a text file to have mixed encoding. Are you sure you mean UTF-8. Perhaps the files are encoded with an 8 bit code page.

Comment: "normally readable by all" - printable or readable? The only chars that can be printed by all character sets in ASCII, which is American English.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I am english and can read only english data. But I have got many other language data which may having some different encoding. Mostly apart from the UTF-8 I suppose

Comment: I'm English too and like a stereotypical Englishman I can only **understand** English. I can read latin characters just fine too: Café, it's where I get my chá from. So what's the problem? Is it that you strictly want only English characters. How do you want them encoded? In ASCII, UTF-16, UTF-32? Do you want to support £? If so, do want that in the Unicode character set or a character set like ISO-8895-1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python3/text_file_processing.html) article will be of help about how to process text files on Python 3

Basically if you use:

```
open(fname, encoding="utf-8", errors="strict")
```

It will raise an exception if the file is not utf-8 encoded, but you can change the [errors handling param](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open) for read the file and apply your algorithm for exclude lines.

By example:

```
open(fname, encoding="utf-8", errors="replace")
```

Will replace non utf-8 characters by a ? symbol.

As @Leon says, you need to consider that Chinese and/or Arabic characters can be utf-8 valid.

If you want a more strict character set you can try to open your file using a latin-1 or a ascii encoding (takin into account that utf-8 and latin-1 are ASCII compatible)

You need to take in count that there are so many character encoding types, and they can be not ASCII compatibles. Is very dificult to read properly text files if you dont know its encoding type, the chardet module can help on that, but is not 100% reliable.

Comment: @JafferWilson can you explain what is not working? what behavior are you expecting and what is happening?

Comment: Cesar, as you have siad a? will be replace by the character whiich is not UTF-8 supported. It didn't work. Again various characters are present in the output file which are not utf-8 characters. this is what I mean. Using python3

Comment: @JafferWilson, when you use open(fname, encoding="utf-8", errors="replace") all data that are not properly utf-8 encoded is replaced, so, all character you obtain, are utf-8 valid. Utf-8 can encode any unicode character, so you can have (attending the last unicode version) 128,237 characters and 135 scripts, so, there can be strange symbols, but this don't mean that they are not utf-8